VSCode non-terminating task before debug
For a little project, I'm using VSCode. To test email outputs, I use a script that just logs incoming SMTP messages.
Now, I'd like to start this script before launching debug. But using "preLaunchTask": "maildummy" in launch.json doesn't work, because pre launch means the task has to terminate before the main debug is run.
And the maildummy is a server listening on a port. So it won't terminate unless told to.
I can, of course, start the dummy by hand, but automating would be nice. Is there a way to do that? Bonus points for shutting it down when debugging terminates.
